# Sending Document to drop off library won't kick off Content Organizer Rules. SP 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, drop-off-library

I would like to move 12000 documents (with attached metadata) to a cross-site library. I planned to do it by utilizing Content Organiser Rule.

My issue is when I move/copy document to the Drop Off library via a Workflow, the Rule I created won't kick off and document just stays in that Drop Off Library.

Ps: If I upload and submit a document to drop off library the rule kicks off without problems.